# How vowels are expressed in musical notation, the case of B5 in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, frequency

I understand that 1000Hz is B5 plus 21 cents.

What is this note and how can it be represented in Lilypond notation?

Comment: I don't understand your question, where did you get this figure of 1000Hz from?

Comment: From Wikipedia for vowels in Spanish: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formante

Comment: I think the fundamental (if you'll pardon the pun) misunderstanding is: "What is this note": When we talk about "a note" we're talking about the fundamental. An oboe, a flute, and a saxophone can all play a C, and they sound different. The differences are in the overtones. Blends of overtones are not normally represented in music staff notation; it's really only customized for representing fundamental pitches.

Comment: If this is for human performance, an easier strategy might be simply to print the desired vowel under the note, with a textual introduction explaining to the performer what you want (and explaining Spanish pronunciation if they're unclear on it), and then leave it to them how to represent the difference. As a violinist, for *e* I'd play closer to the bridge, for *a* farther away, and for *u* maybe play at a higher point on a lower string. Some wind instruments can even "sing" through the instrument...

Comment: It looks like you have a question about representing B5 plus 21 cents in Lilypond, and then some questions about formants that are not connected with music. Can you clean up your question to focus on the on topic bits for this site

Comment: @DoktorMayhem formants are very much connected with music. Knowing about them is useful for singers and critical for those who would program synthesizers to sound like singers.  The question may be a bit off base, but that should not doom it to closure.  I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @phoog - formants can be very connected with music, but not the question the OP has asked about them.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem I disagree. The question concerns vowels, an important topic in music, and frequency, another important topic. On top of that, it concerns staff notation and notation software: OP says, repeatedly, "the question focus on how to represent note B5 (which seems to map with frequency 1kHz) in Lilypond notation."  Suppose the question had been "trying to translate the metric system into a musical composition, I see that the factor 1 kHz would be B5 plus 13 cents...."  Should that be off topic?  Why do you think this question is unconnected to music?

Comment: @phoog - as the OP didn't come back to edit, I have updated the post myself to focus on the key question. The formant bit is the red herring that isn't connected to the musical question.

Comment: To OP's defense, you can try to emulate speech using musical notes, see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6e2c0v4sBM But it doesn't work very well. It has some similarity with vocoders, but also some differences.

Answer (score 9):

> Trying to emulate Spanish vowels sound with musical notes,

Not going to happen, at least not if I understand what you mean by this.  I believe your thought process is as follows:

> > At https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formante there is a chart showing formants F1 and F2 of the vowel /a/ at 700 Hz and 1000 Hz and of /e/ at 660 Hz and 1290 Hz, so if I play two musical notes with the first two frequencies, it should sound like /a/, but with the second pair of frequencies, the two notes will sound like /e/.

There are a number of problems with this line of reasoning.  First, the formant isn't a precise frequency but (from [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant)) a "broad spectral maximum."  It is broad.  This is reflected in the spectrographs as a dark band.  If the formant were a distinct pitch, it would be seen as a narrow line.  If that were the case then normal speech and singing would sound like this:

Instead, this is a rare specialist skill.

The spectrum difference that distinguishes /a/ from /e/ is similar to the spectrum difference that distinguishes an oboe from a flute, a clarinet, a violin, and so on.  This sound spectrum describes the relative strength of the harmonic overtones of the sound, which determine the timbre, and, in human speech, the timbre varies, giving us distinct vowels.  The formants are broad frequency ranges within which the overtones are amplified.  They are not precise pitches.  Two instruments playing together, or two singers singing together, don't sound like a single vowel regardless of what pitches they're playing or singing.

With these thoughts in mind, now, on to your actual question:

> What is [B5 plus 21 cents] and how can it be represented in Lilypond notation?

B5 plus 21 cents is most likely just B5.  Traditional staff notation is not particularly precise about frequency.  Music can be played in a variety of tuning systems, and in many of these systems notes with the same note name can easily vary by more than 20 cents even within one piece.  Even in the context of strict equal temperament, however, there are many orchestras that do not tune A to 440 Hz.  In equal temperament based on A=444 Hz, B5 is 996.75 Hz, only 5.64 cents lower than 1000 Hz.

Traditional staff notation is not very efficient at encoding and communicating such precision of tuning, but that hasn't stopped modern composers from developing extensions to do so.  You might be tempted to turn to these, but even then no musician is going to be able to play a 1000 Hz tone accurately simply because there is something on the page informing them that the note is supposed to be 1000 Hz.  This is a task for computers or electronic instruments.

If I were writing a score for a computer or electronic piece, I would probably just use the text "1000 Hz" above or below the note.

But remember that formants are not as precise as they seem because the frequency given for a formant is the center of a broad spectral range.  It's not a magic number.  If someone sings an /a/ with formants centered at 698 Hz and 988 Hz, it will still be an /a/, just maybe an /a/ of a slightly different color (though these frequency differences are probably too small to be perceptible).  As the formants change in frequency, the vowel color changes.  As you reduce both frequencies, the vowel gets closer to /o/, whereas reducing F1 and raising F2 makes the vowel closer to /i/.  (If you move the formants dynamically during the course of phonation, you get a diphthong such as /ao/ or /ai/.)

If I were, say, writing a piece using vowel formant frequencies as an organizational principle, I'd start off by just using B5 for 1000 Hz.

Comment: [The talking piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muCPjK4nGY4)

Answer (score 5):

Vowels are identified not by single characteristic formants, but they comprise two at least, F1 and F2. On Wikipedia you find following:
Formant graph (why isn't that picture found, I only copy the link?; will see later) or [Formant plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant#Formant_plots).

So, you will need a cluster of notes, i.e. let us rather say frequencies, since notes are associated to a scale, but vowel formants cannot be mapped to one.

Plus, hearing only the formants it is not easy to recognize vowels. That would be simpler if you also render the anti-formant sinks in between, of course damped by -30dB or so. These anti-formats lets you distinguish the same vowels from different voices.

General, design of vowel and other speech sounds is a sound design affair, it has not to do with music much.

Comment: Of course, it's just an approximation to how a vowel would sound. But the question focus on how to represent note B5 (which seems to map with frequency 1kHz) in Lilypond notation. I'm reserving the formants issue for a different question.

Comment: I'm afraid a single frequency is as far off an approximation to a vowel as a hit tuning fork is far off an approximation to a burst of music.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using absolute mode, it's `{ b'' }`, [like Paco Vila said](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/126422/89764). See this [Documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/writing-pitches).

If you want to be really specific, you could probably do something like `{ b''qs }` and raise it to a B5 semi-sharp. That might be useful depending on what you're looking to do.

...what are you looking to do though? Like what's your end goal?

I'm curious

Answer (score 0):

B5 in LilyPond is

```
  { b'' }
```

and its frequency is 987.8 Hz under the [ISO 16 standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/3601.html) assuming the use of [12-TET tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_equal_temperament). I other words, for an A4=440 Hz and the most commonly named equal temperament.

Comment: Does the ISO standard specify equal temperament?  Or any tuning system at all?  If not, B5 could be anywhere from 977.8 Hz to 990.0 Hz (or perhaps even farther afield depending on which pitch is used as the basis for the tuning and on how that pitch is derived from 440 Hz).

Comment: @phoog you are right.
I only cited the ISO standard for the sake of A4=440 Hz. A big whole tone 9/8 worth puts B5 in 990 Hz.

Comment: Thanks.  I've upvoted this answer because, well, it is the only answer actually to address "how can it be represented in Lilypond?"  I posted the comment in part to counteract the idea that A=440 Hz and 12-tone ET are somehow "right" (which of course they may be in certain contexts, but certainly not in all), but mainly to reinforce the notion that the designation of formant frequencies is really very much less precise than the designation of pitches in a scale.